# Потеря размеров изображения при LSB алгоритме

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, стеганография

Задали в университете реализовать LSB алгоритм используя изображения .png формата в качестве подопытного кролика.

Вот такой метод был написан для того, чтобы прятать текст:

```
private void Hide_Text(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.Filter = "PNG файлы(*.png)|*.png";
        save.CheckFileExists = false;
        save.OverwritePrompt = true;
        if (TextToHide.Text != "")
        {
            if (save.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string PathToImageWithText = save.FileName;
                var context = DataContext as ImageContext;
                BitmapSource bs = new BitmapImage(context.ImageUri);
                int stride = (int)bs.PixelWidth * (bs.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8);
                byte[] PngBytes = new byte[(int)bs.PixelHeight * stride];
                bs.CopyPixels(PngBytes, stride, 0);
                BitArray PngBits = new BitArray(PngBytes);

                string text = TextToHide.Text + ";"; ;
                byte[] textBytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(text);
                if(textBytes.Length * 3 > PngBytes.Length)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Количество символов превысило количество пикселей, для текста не хватает места", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    return;
                }
                BitArray textBits = new BitArray(textBytes);

                for (int i = 0; i < text.Count(); i++)
                {
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 16] = textBits[i * 8];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 17] = textBits[i * 8 + 1];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 18] = textBits[i * 8 + 2];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 8] = textBits[i * 8 + 3];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 9] = textBits[i * 8 + 4];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel] = textBits[i * 8 + 5];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 1] = textBits[i * 8 + 6];
                    PngBits[i * bs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 2] = textBits[i * 8 + 7];
                }

                byte[] bytesWithText = new byte[(int)bs.PixelHeight * stride];
                PngBits.CopyTo(bytesWithText, 0);
                WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bs);
                wb.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, bs.PixelWidth, bs.PixelHeight), bytesWithText, stride, 0);
                context.TransformedImage = wb;
                CreateThumbnail(PathToImageWithText, wb.Clone());
            }
        }
    }
```

Все работает, вопрос заключается в другом.
самая главная прелесть LSB в том, размер изображения не меняется в результате того, что вы что-то в него прячете. 
Но вот мое изображение размером 930кб пройдя через все это становится размером 598кб
Может быть кто-то знает, что является причиной подобных изменений??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причиной таких изменений может быть формат PNG в котором данные (т.е. значения пикселей) сжимаются без потерь, а поскольку содержимое изображения меняется, то даже не смотря на то, что высота и ширина остаются прежними, после изменений оно может просто более лучше сжаться.
Попробуйте грузить в формате BMP и сохранять тоже в BMP (в нем сжатия не бывает почти всегда кроме экзотики RLE).